# ERROR: No matching distribution found for stellargraph[demos]==1.2.1

Tags: python, graph, stellargraph

I'm trying to install stellargraph packages in google colab, but I get the following error:

Trying install StellarGraph:

```py
# install StellarGraph if running on Google Colab
import sys
if 'google.colab' in sys.modules:
  %pip install -q stellargraph[demos]==1.2.1
```

and then get:

```bash
ERROR: Ignored the following versions that require a different python version: 0.10.0 Requires-Python >=3.6.0, <3.8.0; 0.11.0 Requires-Python >=3.6.0, <3.8.0; 0.11.1 Requires-Python >=3.6.0, <3.8.0; 0.4.0 Requires-Python >=3.6,<3.7; 0.4.0b0 Requires-Python >=3.6,<3.7; 0.4.1 Requires-Python >=3.5.0, <3.7.0; 0.5.0 Requires-Python >=3.5.0, <3.7.0; 0.6.0 Requires-Python >=3.5.0, <3.7.0; 0.6.1 Requires-Python >=3.5.0, <3.7.0; 0.7.0 Requires-Python >=3.5.0, <3.8.0; 0.7.1 Requires-Python >=3.5.0, <3.8.0; 0.7.2 Requires-Python >=3.5.0, <3.8.0; 0.7.3 Requires-Python >=3.5.0, <3.8.0; 0.8.0 Requires-Python >=3.5.0, <3.8.0; 0.8.1 Requires-Python >=3.5.0, <3.8.0; 0.8.2 Requires-Python >=3.5.0, <3.8.0; 0.8.3 Requires-Python >=3.5.0, <3.8.0; 0.8.4 Requires-Python >=3.5.0, <3.8.0; 0.9.0 Requires-Python >=3.6.0, <3.8.0; 1.0.0 Requires-Python >=3.6.0, <3.8.0; 1.0.0rc1 Requires-Python >=3.6.0, <3.8.0; 1.1.0 Requires-Python >=3.6.0, <3.9.0; 1.2.0 Requires-Python >=3.6.0, <3.9.0; 1.2.1 Requires-Python >=3.6.0, <3.9.0
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement stellargraph[demos]==1.2.1 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for stellargraph[demos]==1.2.1
```

Does anyone know how I could solve it? Is it necessary to install anything additional? Is the package still maintained?

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary solution, you can follow the solution mentioned here.

https://github.com/stellargraph/stellargraph/issues/2084#issuecomment-1512663596

You should first install Tensorflow 2.11.0

```
!pip install tensorflow==2.11.0
```

Then, install the modified python version library from a different repo:

```
!pip install git+https://github.com/VenkateshwaranB/stellargraph.git
```